# How to assign data attribute in css?

Tags: css, custom-data-attribute

I have following CSS:

```
.map-menu .category.selected {
    background-image: url("../img/category-selected.png");
}
```

But I want to assign that to the elements that are included in the data attribute. I can assign a CSS element like this for the data element,

```
[data-id='1]   {
    width: 400px;
}
```

.. I just don't know what I need to do so that it can also be assigned to the category that's in the css. I thought that by placing it like this would work but can't get it to assign correctly:

```
.map-menu .category.selected  [data-id='1']  {
    background-image: url("../img/category-selected1.png");
}
```

Can someone steer me in the right direction? I've not worked in data attributes before.

here's an example of the HTML used for it:

```
<div class="category selected" data-id="1">Art Galleries</div>
```

UPDATE: Figured this out, you just have to really specify what you want to style like this:

```
div.selected[data-id='5']   {
 background-image: url("../img/category-selected.png") !important;
}
```

Comment: As indicated by the syntax highlighting, you are missing a closing quote: `[data-id='1']`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/79qQW/).

Comment: Oh, that was just because of the stackoverflow stuff didn't format correctly. it's adjusted now.

Comment: Could you include complete example css and html

Comment: Hmm I feel like that's already done in the code above for css, but here's the html for when something is selected and the image changes above ^... just want "category selected" added to the data id css so that I can assign it to the element.

Comment: I figured this out, reflected in the post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: Figured this out, you just have to really specify what you want to style like this:

```
div.selected[data-id='5']   {
background-image: url("../img/category-selected.png") !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS works and a full example is available on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wg6hb/):

```
[data-id]{color: red;}
[data-id="1"]{color: blue;}
```

Comment: hmm yeah that works and I can understand how to get "data-id" to assign with css elements, but the trouble I'm having is assigning "data-id" with EXISTING classes in my style sheet.